# debugging a website on a mobile device

Tags: html, angularjs, debugging, mobile, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a website that uses (except for other things) AngularJS. This website works perfectly fine on (example):

1. Google Chrome
2. IE
3. Firefox
4. iOS
5. Android

However I am having problems with Windows 10 mobile as one of the features is not working correctly (to be more precise it is `$interval`).

When testing my app on one of the browsers I view website via Web Inspector and go to background code to inspect where exactly the app fails. However I have no idea how to fix the problems that occur on mobile devices - such as Windows 10 Mobile?

How can one debug websites on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 Mobile has Edge Browser. Try debugging it in that.

This is might be helpful.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/

Comment: thank you! completely forgot about the Edge. Nonetheless, if it fails at e.g. Android Device (I know that apple uses Safari, which is the same as Desktop safari), what browser do they normally use?

Comment: Most of the Android devices use Chrome as their default browser. and Chrome has one the best development tool for mobile. here is a link to help you out.

[Development on Mobile](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

for the debugging tool you can use
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx